# How to impose control access on flash player streaming through RTMP?

Tags: iphone, streaming, flash, rtmp, icecast

I'm using ICECAST and I'm streaming AAC/HE-AACv2 audio/video file through flash player and on iPhone. Both are separate. But when I submit url in WINAMP to stream it's requesting username/password. But when I use it with flash player, it just starts streaming. My case is I want to use same streaming (RTMP) for both website and iPhone app and i want to impose control access over my flash player to authenticate who can see streamed video.

So, I need to allow access to authenticated users only to see flash player or just reject playing. Now, my provider is not supporting control access on flash player, but i need to do it... can u say how i can do this?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.